# Formatting specific elements from a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

How would i convert a table of the format
data = `[[1,0],  [2, 3]  [4, 2]]`
into a list of lists of the format `lst = [[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 2]]` .

I'm trying to get it such that at each row in the table, the same column represents the same variable. Eg. rows 0-2 of the table at column 0, all represent a different value of x. While from rows 0-2 of at column 1, all represent a different value of y.

With the new list of lists, containing a separate list for both x and y values.